# Is there a better way to remove parts with consecutive zeros that have length equal or above threshold?

Tags: python, numpy, performance, signal-processing

### Problem statement:

As stated by the title, I want to remove parts from an 1D array that have **consecutive** *zeros* and **length equal or above** a *threshold*.

---

### My solution:

I produced the solution shown in the following MRE:

```
import numpy as np

THRESHOLD = 4

a = np.array((1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1))

print("Input: " + str(a))

# Find the indices of the parts that meet threshold requirement
gaps_above_threshold_inds = np.where(np.diff(np.nonzero(a)[0]) - 1 >= THRESHOLD)[0]

# Delete these parts from array
for idx in gaps_above_threshold_inds:
    a = np.delete(a, list(range(np.nonzero(a)[0][idx] + 1, np.nonzero(a)[0][idx + 1])))
    
print("Output: " + str(a))
```

Output:

```
Input:  [1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1]
Output: [1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1]
```

---

### Question:

Is there a *less complicated* and *more efficient* way to do this on a numpy array?

---

### Edit:

Based on @mozway comments, I'm editing my question providing some more information.

Basically, the problem domain is:

- I have 1D signals of length ~20.000 samples
- Some parts of the signals have been zeroed due to noise
- The rest of the signal has non-zero values, in the range ~[50, 250]
- Leading and trailing zeros have been removed

My *goal* is to remove the zero parts above a length threshold as I have already said.

#### More detailed questions:

- As far as **numpy** *efficient handling* is concerned, is there a better solution from the one above?
- As far as *efficient* **signal processing techniques** are concerned, is there more suitable way to achieve the desired goal than using numpy?

---

---

### Comments on answers:

Regarding my first concern about *efficient numpy handling*, @mathfux's solution is really great and basically what I was looking for. That's why I accepted this one.

However, the approach by @Jérôme Richard answers my second question and it presents a really high performance solution; really useful if the dataset is extremely big.

*Thanks for your great answers!*

Comment: what is your real use-case? 1D? how many values? which constraints?

Comment: @mozway I edited my question added the "1D" specification, which was implied by the solution. My real use-case is that the array represents a signal, but it doesn't change the essence of my question. That's why I didn't include further elaboration.

Comment: it might change the answer depending on the constraints, anyway I provided you with an answer, have a look and let me know if this works for you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's also possible to find differences of nonzero items, fix the ones that exceeed threshold and reconstruct a sequence in a correct way.

```
def numpy_fix(a):
    # STEP 1. find indices of nonzero items: [0 1 3 8 9 13 19]
    idx = np.flatnonzero(a)
    # STEP 2. Find differences along these indices (also insert a leading zero): [0 1 2 5 1 4 6] 
    df = np.diff(idx, prepend=0)
    # STEP 3. Fix differences of indices larger than THRESHOLD: [0 1 2 1 1 4 1] 
    df[df>THRESHOLD] = 1
    # STEP 4. Given differences on indices, reconstruct indices themselves: [0 1 3 4 5 9 10]
    cs = np.cumsum(df)
    z = np.zeros(cs[-1]+1, dtype=int) # create a list of zeros
    z[cs] = 1 #pad it with ones within indices found
    return z
>>> numpy_fix(a)
array([1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1])
```

(Note that it's correct only if `a` has no leading or trailing zeros)

```
%timeit numpy_fix(np.tile(a, (1, 50000)))
39.3 ms ± 865 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: It seems to me pretty much what I was looking for! Numpy-based and efficient! Btw in my use-case domain the leading and trailing zeros have been removed.

Comment: Elaborate a bit on how you use the ```cs = np.cumsum(df)``` part. It's a nice approach and it worth to be more easily understandable for future readers!

Comment: @lezaf. It's two things you can do here. Whether [read documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) or debug the code. Well, documentation says `np.cumsum` is a cumulative sum of the elements. Not quite informative in case you see it for a first time. That's way debugging is a better choice. I did it for you within my comments.

Comment: I understood how it works. I only suggested to elaborate a bit on this point for future readers because it's not so intuitive.

Answer (score 5):

`np.delete` create a new array every time it is called which is very inefficient. A faster solution is to store all the value to keep in a mask/boolean array and then filter the input array at once. However, this will still likely require a pure-Python loop if done only with Numpy. A simpler and faster solution is to use **Numba** (or Cython) to do that. Here is an implementation:

```py
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.njit('int_[:](int_[:], int_)')
def filterZeros(arr, threshold):
    n = len(arr)
    res = np.empty(n, dtype=arr.dtype)
    count = 0
    j = 0
    for i in range(n):
        if arr[i] == 0:
            count += 1
        else:
            if count >= threshold:
                j -= count
            count = 0
        res[j] = arr[i]
        j += 1
    if n > 0 and arr[n-1] == 0 and count >= threshold:
        j -= count
    return res[0:j]

a = np.array((1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1))
a = filterZeros(a, 4)
print("Output: " + str(a))
```

Here are the result with a random binary array containing 100_000 items on my machine:

```
Reference implementation: 5982    ms
Mozway's solution:          23.4  ms
This implementation:         0.11 ms
```

Thus, the solution is about **54381 faster** than the initial solution and **212 times** faster than the one of Mozway. The code can even be ~30% faster by working *in-place* (destroy the input array) and by telling Numba the array is *contiguous* in memory (using `::1` instead of `:`).

Comment: You cannot compare directly numba (parallelized code) and my single threaded solution ;) nice approach though

Comment: That said, if OP had many datasets of 20k, I wouldn't parallelize at the level of the single array computation, but rather compute arrays in parallel. I'm quite sure the overall result would be comparable to that of numba with many arrays.

Comment: This Numba code is *not parallel* since there is no `parallel=True` set in the decorator. The code can be parallelised but this is quite hard to do efficiently/correctly and it probably not worth it for 20k items (as you pointed out). Thus, this seems fair to compare the two implementations ;) .

Comment: Is it safe to work "in-place" with numba? What happens to the part of RAM that will be disregarded? Will it be released by garbage collector?

Comment: @dankal444 In this case, I think it is safe. Indeed, the part of the array written is already read (and not read again later). Writing in an input parameter array is allowed by Numba (like Numpy functions with an `out` parameter implemented in Numba). The output array will be a Numpy sub-view of the input array. AFAIK, views are managed by Numpy although they are ref-counted like any Python objects. An array can be deleted when there is no view nor any variable referencing it. AFAIK, returning a subview is allowed and Numba *should* update the objects correctly. In practice, it seems to work.

Comment: @dankal444 Even though returning a subview of a modified array would result an undefined behavior, there is an alternative strategy to avoid this in the Numba function: modify the array in the Numba function and return the number of elements kept, then perform the subview with Numpy outside Numba function call. The impact on performance is very small and this is clearly well defined. Anyway, this is a good question because there have been many bugs in the Numba implementation of in-place Numpy-based operations in the past.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Many thanks! Making view outside Numba function is very clever. Hopefully all those "in place" bugs of Numba are gone now, as I plan to use this technique when performance will demand it.

Comment: wow! I like the simplicity of your approach! A straightforward programming solution with the use of an optimization compiler. Nice! However, without the use of numba, @mathfux solution is both really fast and numpy-style.

Answer (score 0):

A quite efficient method is to use `itertools.groupby`+`itertools.chain`:

```
from itertools import groupby, chain
a2 = np.array(list(chain(*(l for k,g in groupby(a)
                           if len(l:=list(g))<THRESHOLD or k))))
```

output:

```
array([1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1])
```

This works relatively fast, for instance on 1 million items:

```
# A = np.random.randint(2, size=1000000)
%%timeit
np.array(list(chain(*(l for k,g in groupby(a)
                      if len(l:=list(g))<THRESHOLD or k))))

# 254 ms ± 3.03 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: I find your solution very interesting, that's why I voted it up! Nevertheless, I would be interested in an optimization, if any, using numpy tricks.

Comment: @lezaf that's why I requested more info on your real life use case ;) I still don't know how many items you expect, if this is always 0/1, what is the expected proportion of 0/1 or chance to find a stretch, etc. That would influence designing a solution

Comment: Btw, I realize I forgot a condition (0s only), I'll update the answer

Comment: In fact, I am interested in a generic solution based on efficient numpy handling. That's why I didn't provide excess problem-specific information. However, I will update my question later with further information since you ask!